# Cursor verus while loop - what are the advantages/disadvantages of cursors?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, database-cursor

Is it a good idea to use while loop instead of a cursor?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of cursors?

Comment: Do you mean a while loop in client side code?

Can you provide an example?

Comment: I agree with Kev, could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think the question author means you can simulate a loop by placing the items to be looped over into a temp table. You can then 'loop' over the items with a WHILE Count(1) <> 0 loop. On each loop you process an item and remove it from the temp table. 

WHERE loop versus CURSOR is thus a good question with regards to performance and other pros/cons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of these depends on the DBMS, but generally:

Pros:

- Outperform loops when it comes to row-by-row processing
- Works reasonably well with large datasets

Cons:

- Don't scale as well
- Use more server resources
- Increases load on tempdb
- Can cause leaks if used incorrectly (eg. Open without corresponding Close)

Answer (score 10):

I'm following this bit of advice:

> [...] which is better: cursors or
>   WHILE loops? Again, it really depends
>   on your situation. I almost always use
>   a cursor to loop through records when
>   necessary. The cursor format is a
>   little more intuitive for me and,
>   since I just use the constructs to
>   loop through the result set once, it
>   makes sense to use the FAST_FORWARD
>   cursor. Remember that the type of
>   cursor you use will have a huge impact
>   on the performance of your looping
>   construct.

— Tim Chapman in [Comparing cursor vs. WHILE loop performance in SQL Server 2008](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/1741/)

The linked article contains simple examples of how to implement each approach.

Comment: Sadly the hyperlinked content is no longer available. I think this is the article: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/1741/

Answer (score 1):

I would ask you what you are doing with that cursor/while loop.

If you are updating or returning data why don't you use a proper WHERE clause. I know people who would say you should never use cursors.