# On what criteria can While loops and Cursors be compared?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, database-cursor

Suppose that I have a query that really must be either a cursor or a while loop. What criteria can be used to judge which should be used?

Notably not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139843/cursor-verus-while-loop-what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-cursors). I'm not trying to ask what the pros/cons of each option is. I'm assuming that I already know that and I'm asking how to come to a decision between the two options when stuck.

Comment: In my 25 years using SQL Server I think I've used an actual cursor possibly once; sometimes I need to execute a procedure for a sequence of parameters or do some other repetetive task for which I always use a while loop, there's no point in having the overhead and complexity of a cursor unless you need its more advanced features such as scrolling or updating

Comment: SQL is a set based language. There aren't many cases where loops of any kind of the best way to solve challenges.

Comment: Given you know the pros and cons, then its just a matter of personal choice... what are you hoping people will tell you?

Comment: You need to use a while loop to iterate through a cursor so not sure what the question is. Perhaps supply some code samples

Comment: I would say cursor 100 percent, but make sure you use read only forward only local static one. While can at best emulate cursor. Only reason for while is if you also insert into the table being looped and want to process those rows also.

Comment: @siggemannen Do you happen to have any links justifying that particular choice of cursor? I also agree that it's the best, but so many people think that `FAST_FORWARD` is all that you need that it's an argument that I struggle to win. Brent Ozar has one good article, but that's all that I've found. Let me know if I should just ask it as a question.

Comment: What one wants from a cursor is for it to fetch all data once quickly and make as little fuss as possible while doing it. If you're not interested in tracking updates or going back on it or making changes, those settings make most sense to me. Local is mostly so it doesn't crash with other cursors named the same, and if you manage to forget to deallocate it, it doesn't hang around, also makes sense in a concurrent system. The various settings are discussed at the microsoft cursor page, i haven't really looked anywhere else for it.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of is comes down to personal preference or whether the other developers you work with have a visceral reaction to seeing a cursor. Personally, the only time I use a cursor is when it can replace having to declare a temporary table with a RID on it, insert rows into it, then do a `WHILE` loop till `@RID <= @MaxRID`

And even then, the main reason I like them is it's easier to write a code snippet to loop using a cursor than it is to stub out the table.

So basically, if I have a scenario where I would have to do something like the following to use a `WHILE` loop...

```
-- Table based approach
declare @loopTable table
(
    RID int identity(1,1),
    TableName nvarchar(128)
)

declare 
    @RID int,
    @MaxRID int,
    @TableName nvarchar(128)

insert into @LoopTable(TableName)
select name
from sys.tables

select 
    @RID = 1,
    @MaxRID = @@rowcount

while @RID <= @MaxRID
begin

    select @TableName = TableName
    from @loopTable
    where RID = @RID
    select 'Do something for ' + @TableName

    select @RID += 1
end
```

I might replace it with...

```
-- Cursor based approach
declare @TableName nvarchar(128)
declare c cursor local fast_forward for
    select name
    from sys.tables
open c

fetch next from c into @TableName

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

    select 'Do something for ' + @TableName
    
    fetch next from c into @TableName

end

deallocate c
```

That's about it. But really, don't underestimate the amount of revulsion many database developers have to cursors. Their logic is clunky, it's sort of hard to understand why you need a `local fast_forward` cursor for them to be acceptable, and there are so many more ways to abuse cursors than to use them properly, that most people I know just steer clear of them.

If you're in doubt, I would reach for a `WHILE` loop instead as, even in the best of circumstances, it will perform the same function as a `local fast_forward` cursor, and be immediately recognizable to other database developers. Unless of course you're working with a crew of people who like cursors better in which case, there's your answer.

Comment: "even in the best of circumstances, it will perform the same function as a local fast_forward cursor" only if it's on an indexed query. Otherwise it is empirically worse than a `STATIC` cursor. `local fast_forward` cursors actually perform better or the same as a `while` in most circumstances. Obviously both should really be avoided.